# Runtime error in nested for loop C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, error-handling, runtime-error

```
 for(i=0;i<np;i++){
    cin >> temp_str;
    pos = find(names.begin(), names.end(), temp_str) - names.begin();
    cin >> total >> ppl;
    giving.push_back(make_pair(pos, total));
    amt_getting = total / ppl;
    bal[pos] += total - (amt_getting * ppl);

    for(j = 0; j < np - 1; j++){   /**** Error due to this loop's condition******/
       cin >> temp_str;
       pos = find(names.begin(), names.end(), temp_str) - names.begin();
       bal[pos] += amt_getting;
    }
```

I am getting a runtime error in my program. This the code fragment where the RTE occurs. Whenever I change the condition `j < np-1` to `j < np` the error gets fixed. What's the matter? I haven't even used any array inside the second `for` loop for segfault.

Comment: What is `np`?  What is it's value?

Comment: `i` and `j`  are they `int` or  `unsigned int` or ...?

Comment: Please post a relevant and valid code along with the error statement.

Comment: log the values of i and j, please; and tell us their vals when it segfaults. Also, if it holds that you  "haven't even used any array in the second for loop",  `bal`is a associative container?

Comment: @Raul That's a bad suggestion. They should reduce the problem to a minimal but complete example using relevant code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're not mentioning what kind of runtime error, so this is conjecture...

With `np - 1`, your code doesn't match the input; there's one non-integer more left in the stream.

This means that `cin >> total >> ppl` fails, `ppl` becomes zero, and `total / ppl` is a division by zero.